# Set pointer to int value

Tags: c++, pointers

Why does the compiler complain when I try to set the value of a pointer to an `int`? On my system, an `int` is the same size as a pointer. The `int` I have contains an address I want to set the pointer to.

```
int addr = 0xffff;
std::uint8_t* ptr = addr;
```

Why isn't this possible without casting `addr`? Is the compiler trying to prevent me from shooting myself in the foot?

Comment: It's the same principle why the earth is round, and the sky is blue. The compiler is complaining because the C++ language specification says that you cannot automatically convert between an `int` and a pointer.

Comment: c++ is a strongly typed language and they are different types.   Why can you assign a Foo to a Bar if they're both the same size?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - The Earth is not round - it is oblate spheroid.

Comment: You can use `-fpermissive` option to have GCC allow it.

Comment: @EdHeal Actually the earth is flat.........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because an `int` is not a `std::uint8_t*`. C++ is a typesafe language.